# jQuery hide dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, hide

I have a dropdown menu that shows with the following jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#block-mln-main-menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.test').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

What I want to achieve is when the user clicks anywhere else on the page, it slides up or hides. I am literally at a loss on how to achieve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

added a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/999/

Comment: onblur event fires when an element loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy can try stop propagation event.

**CSS:**

```
.showup{width:100px;height:100px; background:red; display:none;}
.click{cursor:pointer;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="click">click me</div>
<div class="showup">Click somewhere else!</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.click').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
     $(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
});
$(".showup").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});
```

Comment: Something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/1010/  
You just have to duplicate the same behavior for each sub menu you have in your production menu.

Comment: Great! I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle will only work it user click on the same object it you want to hide it when click elsewhere try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(this).not('#block-mln-main-menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.test').hide(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not really what i meant, I need the dropdown to expand when the user clicks on it and it should close when the user clicks on it again, or when the user clicks outside of the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to show dropdown menu when an user clicks on it. If the user again clicks on it or anywhere on the page it should close.

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.menu-label').on('click', function() { 
  $('.drop-down-menu').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

To hide the menu when user click anywhere on page

```
$('body').on('click', function() { 
  $('.drop-down-menu').addClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need, but after 1 hour of trying it still is not working. Could you maybe create a fiddle so i could understand better?

Comment: I have created this on [codepen] (http://codepen.io/vaibhaviiit/pen/yYbPez). For any help ping here.

Comment: I have done some modification on your code, check  this http://jsfiddle.net/fryy0kve/3/

Comment: Thanks! im going to check it out now

Comment: Well, i dont know whats wrong now... I chcked the fiddle out and tried it on my own, and it works like a charm. When implementing it onto my site, it doesnt work, it does nothing really... Could this be bacause i am using drupal 8 ?

Comment: might be possible, also chek the jquery plugin you have used. If your website is online, provide me link so that I can debug

Comment: Its not live so unfortunately i can't provide a link :( What do you mean exactly with check the jquery plugin i have used ?

Comment: I saw what the problem was at the debugger console, i was missing a $. Thanks Vaibhav !! its working now

Comment: great :)  ping if you need any help.

Comment: Vaibhav, could you help me with 1 more thing if its not to much trouble ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851180/disable-link-in-dropdown-menu-but-keep-the-css

Comment: Thanks, but there is no css on the "bewerkingen" link, and thats what I was trying to do. Also, I just noticed that when you click on something else then "bewerkingen" the dropdown menu still pops up ?

Comment: nvm fixed that last thing, but still the css is not showing because I disabled the link. I am at a loss what to do...

Comment: in case of pointer-events:none, hover will nor work because hover is also a pointer event

Comment: ye so i saw, im now using e.PreventDefault, but its disabling all my links instead of just that 1. http://jsfiddle.net/Blomkfist174/aL7Xe/1006/

Comment: see my ans at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851180/disable-link-in-dropdown-menu-but-keep-the-css or at http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/1003/