# Disable link in dropdown menu but keep the css

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, drop-down-menu

I have the following menu on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/1000/

I disabled the "Bewerkingen" link with :

```
 a[href="/test4/disabled"] {
      pointer-events: none;

}
```

because its a dropdown menu, but when I use that code my css seems to dissapear, how can I fix this? or what code should I use to disable that link but still have my dropdown menu and css on it ? I am using Drupal so using # in the link is not going to work

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: If you dont what the `a` to link to anything can't you not just do `<a href="#">Bewerkingen</a>` ?

Comment: Not possible since I am using drupal, if I use # it redirects to the homepage. The link has to be non clickable

Comment: @urbz A hyperlink with no `href` value is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a href='#'>Bewerkingen</a>
```

You will not need to use

```
a[href="/test4/disabled"] {
      pointer-events: none;

}
```

Comment: then it will redirect me to the home page

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to figure about one way, that's by using js.

**HTML**

```
<a href="/test4/disabled" class="disable-link">Bewerkingen</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.disable-link').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

I will upadte soon if I got some way to do with css

The other solution with css below, You don't need js now.

```
.disable-link {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
 }
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy, but I can't add a class to the href because I am using drupal :( Thanks again tho for helping me

Comment: I found a module that allows me to add classes to certain links, and now it works (6 hours later). Thanks allot Vaibhav for saving my day :)

Comment: Great. which module  are you using?

Comment: "Menu Link Attributes" It's in beta though

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes